# Generating Conditional Random Graphs

Tags: pr.probability, random-graphs, statistical-physics

Let $G(n,p)$ be the usual random graph on $n$ vertices with each edge existing independently with probability $p$ (no self loops , or double edges not are allowed). I would like to simulate the distribution of a random graph given the event $T\geq a$ where $T$ is the number of triangles in the random graph. The natural approach is Metropolis Hastings. I've already found some semi-efficient algorithms that approximate the number of triangles in a given random graph, however I am still at a loss of what Markov chain to pick for a good rate of convergence. I would immensely appreciate a push in the right direction. In particular, some references would be fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: what value of $a$ are you interested in? Also, if you are interested in computing expectations of the form $E[\phi(G) | T(G) \geq a]$, importance sampling might just work as well.

Comment: My question would be: which values of $p$ are you interested in? Are you talking about the regime where you expect to have lots of triangles or few?

Comment: @Alekk: I am interested in all values of $a$ but in particular for $a>E(T)$ which is on the order of $n^3p^3/6$. I'm not so much interested in calculating expectations as just seeing what the graphs look like.

Comment: @Anthony Quas: I would be interested in all (fixed) values of $p$. What I am sure of is the number of triangles is expected to be much less than $a$, which translates to $P(T\geq a)$ being very small by itself. 

Comment: @Alex R: just being curious but how are you planning to "see what the graphs look like"? For small graphs that might be easy to plot some of them, but for large graphs I think that you are going to compute some expectations (number of copie of K_4, is it connected, etc...), aren't you?

Comment: @Alekk: my apologies for being vague. Yes in particular I would be looking at such things as the number of cliques. My hope is that for large (but not too large!) $n$ I can do some basic counting to check some estimates that I have.

Comment: so if you want to count cliques, you might as well use importance sampling (associated with the cross entropy method for example, wich is well adapted to rare events simulation).

Comment: @Alekk: If I do importance sampling, for my importance sampling distribution would I pick $G(n,p')$ where say $p' >> p $? My reasoning is that I will ultimately need to compute ratios of densities and for even something as simple as triangle counts, while I can count the number of triangles in a particular instance of $G(n,p)$, I have no way of knowing what the normalization factor is (for say $P(T=a)$)